# Gridview Sort Causing RowDataBound to not function correctly

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a gridview that works just fine with each of my row commands, however, once it is sorted it causes the rowdatabound event to use incorrect values rather than the actual values in the row after it has been sorted. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code behind.

```
 //Verify and Update Record
protected void UnverifiedSalesGV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    buttonCommand = e.CommandName;
    MessageLBL.Text = "";

    if (e.CommandName == "VerifyRecord")
    {

        //Get record ID
        string salesID = UnverifiedSalesGV.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();

        //Get productID 
        SalesData getSalesRecord = new SalesData();
        getSalesRecord.GetRowValuesSalesID(salesID);

        string productID = getSalesRecord.productID;


        if (productID != "38")
        {
            verifyRenewal = false;
            try
            {
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Sales SET Verified = @Verified WHERE ID = @ID";
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = UnverifiedSalesGV.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateParameters["Verified"].DefaultValue = true.ToString();
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.Update();

                UnverifiedSalesGV.DataBind();
                VerifiedSalesGV.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageLBL.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                MessageLBL.Text = "Could not verify sale. Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Get row index.
            UnverifiedSalesGV.SetEditRow(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            verifyRenewal = true;
        }
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "UpdateProduct")
    {

        DropDownList productValue = (DropDownList)UnverifiedSalesGV.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("RenewalProductDDL");
        if (productValue.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Sales SET ProductID = @ProductID, Verified = @Verified WHERE ID = @ID";
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = UnverifiedSalesGV.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateParameters["ProductID"].DefaultValue = productValue.SelectedValue;
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.UpdateParameters["Verified"].DefaultValue = true.ToString();
                UpdateSalesRecordSDS.Update();

                UnverifiedSalesGV.DataBind();
                UnverifiedSalesGV.EditIndex = -1;
                VerifiedSalesGV.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageLBL.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                MessageLBL.Text = "Could not verify sale. Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageLBL.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            MessageLBL.Text = "Please select renewal type.";
        }

    }
    if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRecord")
    {
        //Get date and user info
        DateTime getDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        string activeuser = user.UserName;

        try
        {
            //Get dropdown and textbox values
            string commisionMonth;
            string grossSalesAmount;
            string netSalesAmount;
            string notes;

            TextBox grossSalesValue = (TextBox)UnverifiedSalesGV.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("GrossSalesTXT");
            TextBox netSalesValue = (TextBox)UnverifiedSalesGV.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("NetSalesTXT");
            TextBox notesValue = (TextBox)UnverifiedSalesGV.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("NotesTXT");
            DropDownList commissionMonthValue = (DropDownList)UnverifiedSalesGV.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("CommissionMonthDDL");
            grossSalesAmount = grossSalesValue.Text;
            netSalesAmount = netSalesValue.Text;
            commisionMonth = commissionMonthValue.SelectedValue;
            notes = notesValue.Text;

            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [Sales] SET [GrossSalesAmount] = @GrossSalesAmount, [NetSalesAmount] = @NetSalesAmount, [Notes] = @Notes, [CommissionMonth] = @CommissionMonth, [DateLastModified] = @DateLastModified, [UserLastModified] = @UserLastModified WHERE [ID] = @ID";
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["GrossSalesAmount"].DefaultValue = grossSalesAmount;
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["NetSalesAmount"].DefaultValue = netSalesAmount;
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["CommissionMonth"].DefaultValue = commisionMonth;
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["Notes"].DefaultValue = notes;
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["DateLastModified"].DefaultValue = getDate.ToString();
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["UserLastModified"].DefaultValue = activeuser;
            UnverifiedSalesSDS.UpdateParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = UnverifiedSalesGV.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();


            UnverifiedSalesSDS.Update();
            UnverifiedSalesGV.DataBind();
            UnverifiedSalesGV.EditIndex = -1;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageLBL.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            MessageLBL.Text = "Could not update record. Message: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

}

//Get product
protected void UnverifiedSalesGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {

        if (buttonCommand == "VerifyRecord")
        {
            //Get record ID
            string salesID = UnverifiedSalesGV.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.DataItemIndex)].Value.ToString();

            //Get productID 
            SalesData getSalesRecord = new SalesData();
            getSalesRecord.GetRowValuesSalesID(salesID);

            string productID = getSalesRecord.productID;

            if (productID == "38")
            {
                //Items to Hide/Display
                Button UpdateProductBTN = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("UpdateProductBTN");
                Button UpdateBTN = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("UpdateBTN");
                Label productLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("CurrentProductLBL");
                DropDownList productDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("RenewalProductDDL");
                Label grossSalesLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("GrossSalesLBL");
                TextBox grossSalesTXT = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("GrossSalesTXT");
                Label netSalesLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("NetSalesLBL");
                TextBox netSalesTXT = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("NetSalesTXT");
                Label commissionMonthLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("SalesCommissionLBL");
                DropDownList commissionMonthDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("CommissionMonthDDL");
                TextBox notesTXT = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("NotesTXT");


                UpdateProductBTN.Visible = true;
                UpdateBTN.Visible = false;
                productLBL.Visible = false;
                productDDL.Visible = true;
                grossSalesLBL.Visible = true;
                grossSalesTXT.Visible = false;
                netSalesLBL.Visible = true;
                netSalesTXT.Visible = false;
                commissionMonthLBL.Visible = true;
                commissionMonthDDL.Visible = false;
                notesTXT.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem by hardcoding in the following:

```
 //Hide and show fields
protected void UnverifiedSalesGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == rowIndex)
    {
        string state = e.Row.RowState.ToString();
        if (state == "Alternate, Edit" || state == "Edit")
        {

            //Get record ID
            string salesID = UnverifiedSalesGV.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.DataItemIndex)].Value.ToString();

            //Get productID 
            SalesData getSalesRecord = new SalesData();
            getSalesRecord.GetRowValuesSalesID(salesID);

            string productID = getSalesRecord.productID;

            if (productID == "38")
            {
                //Items to Hide/Display
                Button UpdateProductBTN = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("UpdateProductBTN");
                Button UpdateBTN = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("UpdateBTN");
                Label productLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("CurrentProductLBL");
                Label accountManagerLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("AccountManagerLBL");
                DropDownList productDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("RenewalProductDDL");
                DropDownList accountManagerDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("AccountManagerDDL");
                Label grossSalesLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("GrossSalesLBL");
                TextBox grossSalesTXT = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("GrossSalesTXT");
                Label netSalesLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("NetSalesLBL");
                TextBox netSalesTXT = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("NetSalesTXT");
                Label commissionMonthLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("SalesCommissionLBL");
                DropDownList commissionMonthDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("CommissionMonthDDL");
                TextBox notesTXT = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("NotesTXT");
                Label notesLBL = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("NotesLBL");


                UpdateProductBTN.Visible = true;
                UpdateBTN.Visible = false;
                productLBL.Visible = false;
                productDDL.Visible = true;
                accountManagerLBL.Visible = true;
                accountManagerDDL.Visible = false;
                grossSalesLBL.Visible = true;
                grossSalesTXT.Visible = false;
                netSalesLBL.Visible = true;
                netSalesTXT.Visible = false;
                commissionMonthLBL.Visible = true;
                commissionMonthDDL.Visible = false;
                notesTXT.Visible = false;
                notesLBL.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```